# How to fill a TextBox like a print receipt content using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Point of Sale application and I have a `TextBox` that will act as the content of the receipt. It will have a Dot Matrix Font and will simulate the receipt printed.

[image]

What I want to do is to create a class that will handle the fill of that receipt.

I know that the Max characters width are 25 letters. So I should be able to append text to this class and it will automatically position the text where it should be.

So I should get something like this:

[image]

Is there any class out there than can position the text automatically? Or I have to do by hand everything?

Comment: If in WPF, why use a TextBox for this? An ItemsControl would serve you much better. Even in WinForms you have better options

Comment: Just added tag "winforms".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter above said, it would be cleaner to actually use controls to create the listing, but you can do it with strings if you have to.

Using `string.Format`, you can pad to a certain width using positive values for right aligned text and negative for left aligned:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

From that page:

```
int[] years = { 2013, 2014, 2015 };
int[] population = { 1025632, 1105967, 1148203 };
String s = String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10}\n\n", "Year", "Population");
for(int index = 0; index < years.Length; index++)
    s += String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10:N0}\n",
                  years[index], population[index]);
// Result:
//    Year       Population
//
//    2013       1,025,632
//    2014       1,105,967
//    2015       1,148,203
```